# 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'get_values'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, gspread

Yesterday I had a problem in the authorization to connect with gspread and I found a solution [here](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/1014#issuecomment-1082446914). But now I got the error ***'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'get_values'***, despite the code being the same.

```
import gspread
from google.colab import auth
from google.auth import default

auth.authenticate_user()
creds, _ = default()
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

url_sheet = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../"
sheet = gc.open_by_url(url_sheet)
wsheet_values = sheet.worksheet('Sheet Name').get_values('A:G') #line with error
```

[Here](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.3.0/api.html?highlight=get_values()#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.get_values) and [here](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) says that it is possible to use "get_values()" with a worksheet. Does anyone know what it could be?

**Update**

When I tried to import just the function:

```
from gspread.worksheet.Worksheet import get_values
```

I got this:

> cannot import name **'Dimension' from 'gspread.utils'** (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gspread/utils.py)

Answer (score 3):

I just solved the problem replacing "get_values" with "get":

```
url_sheet = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../"
sheet = gc.open_by_url(url_sheet)
wsheet_values = sheet.worksheet('Sheet Name').get('A:G') #it works for me!
```

But I still don't know why it stopped accepting "get_values"...

**Update:**
I was told it's actually a bug of the latest release: https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/1018